# Disabling horizontal scroll bar in EXTJS panel

Tags: extjs

Team,

Is anyone aware how to disable horizontal scroll bar in panel. I am using EXTJS 3.4

Basically I want only vertical scroll bar to be visible and not horizontal.

I tried autoScroll=true as panel property but If I do so I can see both horizontal and vertical scroll bar.

here is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World Window</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


    Ext.onReady(function(){
        var tab2 = new Ext.FormPanel({
            labelAlign: 'left',
            labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;',
            labelWidth: 85,
            title: 'Run Report',
            bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
            border : true,
            style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50',
            width: 900,
            height:600, 
                  items:
                  [{

                      xtype:'panel',
                      border:true,
                      height:75,
                      title:'Inner Panel',
                      bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
                      autoScroll:true,
                  items: [{
                    layout:'column',
                    border :false,
                    items:[{
                        columnWidth:.3,
                        layout: 'form',
                        border :false,
                        items: [{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                            name: 'first',
                            anchor:'95%'
                        }, {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Company',
                            name: 'company',
                            anchor:'95%'
                        }]
                    },{
                        columnWidth:.3,
                        layout: 'form',
                        border :false,
                        items: [{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                            name: 'last',
                                          anchor:'95%'
                        },{
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Email',
                            name: 'email',
                            vtype:'email',
                            anchor:'95%'
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
             }]
        ,
            buttons: [{
            text: 'Save'
            },{
            text: 'Cancel'
            }]
        });

    tab2.render(document.body); 


});
</script> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice to see how you consider the entire stackoverflow community as part of your team!

Answer (score 17):

The solution is to set overflowY to 'auto' and then remove autoScroll completely.

```
xtype:'panel',
border:true,
height:75,
title:'Inner Panel',
bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
//autoScroll:true,
overflowY: 'auto'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Using 4.2.1 what works for me in Chrome, FF and IE11 is using this:

```
style: 'overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but this is the actual setting to use:

```
bodyStyle:'overflowY: auto',
```

Hope it helps someone.  Should be able to get it to work in 4.x implementations too.  So far I only tested it in 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

```
// autoScroll:true,
// style:'overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;',
overflowY: 'auto',
```

It works with replacing comments with overflowY.